# python - Concatenate list elements in every possible way

Tags: python, combinations, nested-lists

My issue might be quite difficult to explain (maybe that's also the reason I did not find a solution or a similar problem).

What I have is a list with some elements (in my specific case also lists).
What I want is having every possible combinations of concatenations of this list in the same order.

For example:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]  # what I have

{                     # what I want
    [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
    [[1, 2], [3], [4]],
    [[1], [2, 3], [4]],
    [[1], [2], [3, 4]],
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]],  # Update 1
    [[1, 2, 3], [4]],
    [[1], [2, 3, 4]],
    [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
}
```

In general the length of the sublists is greater then 1; also the list itself may have more than 4 elements.

Any help is highly appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
added missing combination in code.

Comment: itertools.combinations

Comment: What happened to `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I had the same thought.  In general, the number of result lists should always be a power of two if I understand the problem correctly (it should be 2**(n-1) where n is the original list length).

Comment: @TomKarzes...I don't think so, the OP included a case with 3 sub lists

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for your remark, I added this case as well.

Comment: @Iron Fist the OP's sample input has 4 sublists.  2**(4-1) is 8, which is the correct number of output cases.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with non-sequential numbers, too? Ex. `[[2],[4],[3],[1]]` or `[[3],[0],[7],[4]]`

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom yes, the content of the sublists is actually irrelevant in the sense that I want it to be combined with adjacent sublists.

Comment: @Praveen could you kindly elaborate on that? I found several ideas/questions with itertools.combinations, but none of them fitted my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def concats(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return [l]

    return [[l[0]] + x for x in concats(l[1:])] + \
           concats([l[0] + l[1]] + l[2:])
```

Here's a sample case:

```
l = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
r = concats(l)
```

And the result:

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
 [[1], [2], [3, 4]],
 [[1], [2, 3], [4]],
 [[1], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[1, 2], [3], [4]],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [4]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Edit:  It wasn't clear to me how the empty list should be handled, but in that case you may want to simply return an empty list without wrapping it in an outer list - I'll leave that case up to you.  A simple check at the top of the function can handle it any way you choose (and it won't affect the larger cases).

Comment: this is amazing, exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)  I also just added a note at the bottom about the empty list case, since I wasn't sure how that should be handled.